# Combing UI and API in a single Blazor server app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, blazor, blazor-server-side

I’m going to build my first Blazor Server app that will have a web front end and some APIs. Those APIs will need to be called buy other applications as well. Currently our on-prem app uses a separate IIS website for the UI and another IIS website for the Web APIs. Is there any reason why I shouldn’t be able to combine those into a single Blazor Server app? I’m not seeing any reason not to other than seeing a couple posts during my research that says to keep them separated in production. Also, most videos for training seem to use WASM over Server for their examples.

Answer (score 3):

There are some benefits to keeping the front-end and APIs separate in **production**. For example, if they have to **scale independently** or if you want to be able to **update** them separately. In this case, it might be more efficient to have them as **separate applications**. That way, you can scale each one based on its own **traffic** and **resource** needs. And if you need to make changes to one, it won't affect the other.

Ultimately, whether to combine or separate a Blazor Server front-end and APIs into a single application will depend on your specific needs. If the front-end and APIs are **closely related** and don't need to scale separately, it might make sense to have them in the **same app**. But if they're more independent or need to scale on their own, it might be better to keep them separate.